# Create parent and child models in the same commit

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the following models:

```
App.Offers = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),            
   createdBy: DS.belongsTo('App.Users'),
   products: DS.hasMany('App.Products'), 
   startDate: DS.attr('string'),
   endDate: DS.attr('string')
}

App.Products = DS.Model.extend({
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    img: DS.attr('string'),
    offer: DS.belongsTo('App.Offers'),
}
```

Using these two models I create both an offer (parent) and a product (child):

```
var offer = App.Offers.createRecord({/*fields*/}),
    product = App.Products.createRecord({/*fields*/});
offer.get('products').pushObject(product);
offer.get("store").commit();
```

When I do this the problem is that the parent needs the id of the child and the child the id of the parent in order to set its FK.

I looked up issues and PRs in the ember-data repo and I found this: https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/440 . It suggests wrapping createRecord in a waitForParents function which basically creates the parent and then the child. While I have tried their suggestion I still can't create my records. The problem is that even though the request for the parent is made first, it still needs the id of the child (which is not created yet). The parent request is send with the following payload:

```
{/*other_fields*/,"products":["/api/v1/products//"]}
```

Note the missing id of the product in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it by following the suggestion in this PR: https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/437. They basically suggested creating a waitForParents function and wrap it around createRecord. This function checks if there's a belongsTo relationship and defers the code execution for that creation until the parent is created (by adding an observer to the id field).

In my case I had to override addHasMany in the serializer as well.

I hope that helps other people with the same problem.